# Associative array from text

Tags: c#, regex

How do I parse text which is formated like this?

```
Data
    Name of a group:
        Name:    Value
        Name:          Value
        Name:   Value
Data
    Name of a group:
        Name:   Value
    Name of a group:
        Name:  Value
        Name:     Value
```

It can have multiple `Data` and each data can have multiple `Named groups` and inside every one of them can be multiple `Name Value` pairs also number of spaces can vary inside whole text that means that before first `Data` there can be two spaces and before second none at all.

After parsing I would like to be able to get associative array so I can access data in this way `data[0][Name of group][Value name]` or doing foreachs and so on. Is this even possible with power of regular expression?

Comment: I don't think that's a regular language (hunch only), so I would doubt that it is paseable via regex.  However, it would be simple to create a forward-only parser that breaks up the text into individual data groups, containing zero or more named groups, with zero or more name/value pairs.  Could hack that up in ten minutes or less.

Comment: Why not use JSON or XML, why is your data in that unknown format anyway?

Comment: @RezoMegrelidze Its simply how data Im trying to parse look like. There is nothing I can do about it

Comment: @Hnus Where did you get that text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do without regular expressions. Just scan the input line by line. If line contains the string `"Data"` you increment `data_index` (initially set to -1). If the line looks like `"text:"` you set a variable `group_name` to `text`. If the line looks like `"text_left:text_right"` you set a variable `name` to `text_left` and perform the operation `data[data_index][group_name][name] = text_right`.

To check that a string is a group name, first trim it then check that last character is `':'`. If it's not a data line and not a group name, you can infer that it's a name/value pair.

This assumes that the input file is well-formatted: group names always end with `':'`  and so on. Spaces in lines don't matter.

Comment: It occurred to me but I thought that doing it with regex would be much faster and that regular expressions exist for that kind of tasks so you dont have to write your own algorithm for parsing data. But I guess for something that simple and fairly well formated Ill go with solution you proposed.